# Downvote pop-up is overlapped by the question, if the question is transparent

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

### A picture says more than a thousand words

As you can see, the pop-up that tells me, that I have downvoted this question gets overlapped by the question itself:

> [image: Strange overlapping stuff]

**EDIT**: This also happens on other message boxes:

> [image: Strange overlapping stuff, Volume 2]

**EDIT** 2: This shows the issue in Opera 11.61 (Thank you, Rocket):

> [image: Opera]

Comment: What browser? Is this happening with other messages?

Comment: Browser is Chromium 17.0.963.56 on Ubuntu 11.10.

Comment: Is this happening with other messages?

Comment: What do you mean with "other messages"?

Comment: Try invoking more orange messages for example post two comments in a row - there should be 30 seconds diff and if you try to post before, orange message appears as well.

Comment: Ok, I updated my post with another message box.

Comment: So this is most likely `z-index` issue with the styles of orange box and "faded" text.

Comment: I'm seeing the same issue in `Chrome 18.0.1025.58 beta-m` and `Firefox 11` (well, actually [`Waterfox`](http://waterfoxproject.org/)).  It seems to work ok in `IE 9`.

Comment: In `Opera 11.61`, it looks a little different.  Both the post and orange box are transparent, but the orange box it on top.  http://i.imgur.com/eQkaq.png

Comment: What is the status on this one?

Comment: @PeeHaa hopefully devs are like us and can be lured by some shiny rep :)

Comment: Is this a question or a bug report?

Comment: @VeeruAS this is a bug.

Answer (score 4):

This bug has been targeted and destroyed.  The error messages should no longer take on the opacity of the transparent div after the next build.

Comment: Since this issue has been reported so many times, I'm pretty sure you win Meta for the month for fixing it. Please come to the prize booth to claim your unicorn.

Comment: This probably fixes the same problem [on the elections page](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/140060/when-voting-on-a-candidate-who-withdrew-in-an-election-the-notification-appears), if you want to confirm and mark it [meta-tag:status-completed]. The [flagging dialog](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/140809/dont-change-the-transparency-for-dialogs-shown-on-posts-with-a-score-lower-than) has a similar problem, but that's likely a separate fix.

Comment: Thanks for the links to the meta posts @Tim - I can't wait to see my prize :)