# Dialog rendering below text of answer instead of above

Tags: bug

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Downvote pop-up is overlapped by the question, if the question is transparent](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/124995/downvote-pop-up-is-overlapped-by-the-question-if-the-question-is-transparent)

On Meta, the "your vote is now locked" dialog seems to be rendering beneath the text of the answer:

[image: wat]

Comment: @jadarnel27 I'm no longer experiencing the issue on SO, but I *am* still seeing it on Meta.

Comment: Hmm... this leads me to believe it happens only with "gray style" posts which are highly downvoted - couldn't reproduce with ordinary posts.

Comment: @ShaDowWizArd That's exactly what the other post is reporting =)  Although they don't mention it in the question body, the title says "*...if the question is transparent*"