# Downvote tooltip placed underneath code block

Tags: bug

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Downvote pop-up is overlapped by the question, if the question is transparent](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/124995/downvote-pop-up-is-overlapped-by-the-question-if-the-question-is-transparent)

I just downvoted an answer and wasn't able to read the text in the tooltip because it was placed underneath a code block in the answer.

This happened in a Chrome like browser version 16.

The post I used in the example below is here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2773421/444991.

[image]

Comment: I can't the find the downvoted answer, where is it?

Comment: Same goes for flagging-dialogs on downvoted answers.

Comment: @starx: the answer seems to have been hidden from view when it reached 4 downvotes.

Comment: Suddenly, I can see it now

Comment: Feel free to upvote the dupe report :)

Comment: I apologize for the noise! I wanted to help and searched for duplicates but couldn't find any - but then again I didn't search for `pop-up` (vs. `tooltip`).

Answer (score 1):

It must be a `z-index` problem, while adding extra transparent effect to the answer.

I am sure It will be a fixed.

Comment: I'd guess that it's some minor CSS problem. I just wanted to report it, and I thought this is the right place for it.