# "consider adding a comment" pop-up appearing behind gray answers

Tags: bug, down-votes, design

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Downvote pop-up is overlapped by the question, if the question is transparent](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/124995/downvote-pop-up-is-overlapped-by-the-question-if-the-question-is-transparent)

I down voted an answer that was printed in gray (because of the many down votes it already had), but the pop-up appeared behind it. (Possibly a wrong `z-index`?)

[image: screenie]

I'm running Safari 5 on Mac OS X Lion.