# Minor UI bug with pop up when voting on disabled answer

Tags: bug, user-interface

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Downvote pop-up is overlapped by the question, if the question is transparent](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/124995/downvote-pop-up-is-overlapped-by-the-question-if-the-question-is-transparent)

While voting on a disabled answer, this is how the "Add a comment" message pops up.
[image]