# When voting on a candidate who withdrew in an election, the notification appears behind the text

Tags: bug, election

[image]

Just looks a bit weird. I don't know why I was voting for someone who withdrew anyway...

Comment: Technically it's not behind, just semi-transparent like the withdrawn nomination

Comment: Admit it, it's because you were deliberating hunting for bugs.

Comment: I saw that too but thought it was just some transient Chrome weirdness.

Comment: Likely the same issue as [Downvote pop-up is overlapped by the question, if the question is transparent](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/124995), but I'd have to look into it more.