# Don't change the transparency for dialogs shown on posts with a score lower than −2

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, flags, flag-dialog

If you flag a comment for a post with score of at least −3, for example [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7472941/225647) (the links is for Stack Overflow's 10k users), the dialog box will appear as in the following screenshot.

> [image: Safari screenshot]

It would be preferable not to change the transparency of the dialog box, as it doesn't have any purpose. I don't need to be reminded I am flagging a comment for a post with a low score; that is already evident by looking at the post itself.

The screenshot has been taken on Safari 5.1.7, but I get a similar effect on Google Chrome 20.0.1132.57, and Firefox 14. (I know, Firefox 14 is a beta version.)

> [image: Google Chrome screenshot]
>
> [image: Firefox screenshot]

As side note, the editor buttons cover the dialog box, in the last two screenshots.

Comment: [The flag pop up on heavily downvoted answers has grey text](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40111/the-flag-pop-up-on-heavily-downvoted-answers-has-grey-text) says `status-completed`…

Comment: This is not about grey text; it's about the transparency of the dialog box. Looking at the screenshot shown in the other question, it doesn't seen the dialog box's transparency is altered.

Comment: Out of curiosity: what would you have flagged this as?

Comment: @Pekka I was flagging a comment, and the first one is a reply to a comment that doesn't exist anymore.

Comment: Related: [Downvote pop-up is overlapped by the question, if the question is transparent](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/124995)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Opacity for the comment flagging dialog will be fixed in the next build.