# z-index issue on error pop-up

Tags: bug

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Downvote pop-up is overlapped by the question, if the question is transparent](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/124995/downvote-pop-up-is-overlapped-by-the-question-if-the-question-is-transparent)

When a question gets some downvotes it gets "blurry". When the error pop-up shows it goes behind the code blocks of the question.

[image: z-index issue]

P.S. Browser is Chrome and only tested in Chrome :-)